# Transactional Emails Unchanged, One Installation, Two Stores

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, transactional-mail

There is one Magento 1.9 Community Edition Installation with two Stores. Let's call them "Store A" and "Store B". After following instructions from various articles here and around the internets and creating the proper templates for "Store B" I still get the styles of "Store A" in the transactional emails.

There is a name change in the proper variable verifying the email comes from the correct store but no style change.

P.S.

1. System > Transactional Emails > Store B Template - OK
2. System > Configuration (under the Store B scope) > Sales > Sales
   Emails > Setting set to Store B Template - OK
3. Cache Cleared and tried several times
4. The email-inline.css is used for both, but with different and proper classes
5. The preview gives the proper output

Any ideas? What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was testing the emails locally with mailcatcher using ScotchBox as my Web and Email Server. The problem was that I was getting the admin versions of it and not the real sales emails. I ran a cron job (cron.php) and I captured the proper emails with the right styles.